# How to run multiple threads at the same time in ruby while working with a file?

Tags: ruby, windows, multithreading

I've been messing around with Ruby and threading a little bit today. I have a list of proxies that I want to check. Assuming a timeout of 10 seconds going through a very large list of proxies will take many hours if I write something that goes like:

```
  proxies.each do |proxy|
   check_proxy(proxy)
  end
```

My first problem with trying to figure out threads is how to START multiple at the same exact time. I found a neat little snippet of code online:

```
for page in pages
  threads << Thread.new(page) { |myPage|

    puts "Fetching: #{myPage}\n"
    doc = Hpricot(open(myPage.to_s)).to_s
    puts "Got #{myPage}:  #{doc.size}"
  }
end
```

Seems to work nicely as far as starting them all at the same time. So now I can... start checking all 7 thousand records at the same time?

How do I go to a file, take out a line for each thread, run a batch of like 20 and repeat the process?

Can I run a while loop that in turn starts 20 threads at the same (which remove lines from a file) and keeps going until the file is blank?

I'm a little weak on the logic of what I'm supposed to do.

Thanks guys!

PS.

Another thought: Will there be file access issues if 20 workers are constantly messing with it randomly? What would be a good way around that if this is so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword you are after is [threadpool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern). You can either try to find one for Ruby (I am sure there's couple at least on Github), or roll your own.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6558913/82592) a simple implementation here on SO.

Re: the file access, IMO you shouldn't let workers alter the file directly, but do it in your main thread. You don't want to allow simultaneous edits there.

Comment: To do the file altering in the main thread, you'd have the workers return values to the main thread, and let the main thread do the editing, right?

Comment: I guess so. Or letting threads edit it, but securing exclusive editing rights using mutex I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use gem DelayJob:
https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to generate that many Threads in order to do this work.  In fact generating a lot of Threads can decrease the overall performance of your application.  If you handle checking each proxy asynchronously, without blocking, you can get by with far fewer threads.

You'd create a file manager thread to process the file.  Each line gets added as a request to an array(request queue).  On the other end of the request queue you can use [eventmachine](http://rubyeventmachine.com/) to send the requests without blocking.  eventmachine would also be used to receive the responses and handle the timeout.  The response can then be placed on another array(response queue) which your file manager thread polls.  The file manager thread pulls the responses from the response queue and resolves if the proxy exists or not.

This gets you down to just creating two threads.  One issue that you will have is limiting the number of requests that have been sent since this model will be able to send out all of the requests in less than a second and flood the nearest router.  In my experience you should be able to have around 500 outstanding requests at any one time.

There is more than one way to solve this problem asynchronously but hopefully the above is enough to help get you started with non-blocking I/O.

Comment: I was thinking that you might run into thread safety issues by just using arrays as queues.  There is a [Queue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6558913/125847) class in stdlib that you can use instead.