# JDialog does not appear

Tags: java, swing, awt, java-8, jdialog

The program mostly works correctly, but does not open any window. It should show a little dialog on the bottom right of the desktop. But to another person however, compiling the same code works without problems.We have the same Java Runtime (1.8_u40). How can I fix this?

I have put the code below:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ProgressDialog {
    private JDialog dialogFrame;
    private JProgressBar progressBar;
    private JLabel headingLabel;
    private Uploader callerUploader;

    public ProgressDialog() {

        dialogFrame = new JDialog();
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.toString());
        }

        dialogFrame.setSize(200, 50);
        dialogFrame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.weightx = 1.0;
        constraints.weighty = 1.0;
        constraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

        headingLabel = new JLabel();
        Font f = headingLabel.getFont();
        f = new Font(f.getFontName(), Font.BOLD, f.getSize());
        headingLabel.setFont(f);
        headingLabel.setOpaque(false);
        dialogFrame.add(headingLabel, constraints);
        dialogFrame.setUndecorated(true);

        // Bottone
        constraints.gridx = 1;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.weightx = 0;
        constraints.weighty = 0;

        JButton xButton = new JButton("X");
        xButton.setMargin(new Insets(1, 4, 1, 4));
        xButton.setFocusable(false);
        dialogFrame.add(xButton, constraints);

        // Progress bar
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.weightx = 1.0;
        constraints.weighty = 1.0;
        constraints.gridwidth = 2;

        progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setMaximum(100);
        progressBar.setMinimum(0);
        Dimension dim = new Dimension();
        dim.width = 130;
        dim.height = 20;
        progressBar.setMinimumSize(dim);
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        progressBar.setBorderPainted(true);
        dialogFrame.add(progressBar, constraints);

        xButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dialogFrame.dispose();
                stoppedUploaderClose();
            }
        });
    }

    private void autoPosition() {
        // Per il posizionamento in basso a destra
        Dimension scrSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        // altezza taskbar
        Insets toolHeight = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(dialogFrame.getGraphicsConfiguration());
        dialogFrame.setLocation(scrSize.width - 5 - dialogFrame.getWidth(), scrSize.height - 5 - toolHeight.bottom
                - dialogFrame.getHeight());
    }

    public void destroy() {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    for (float i = 1.00f; i >= 0; i -= 0.01f) {
                        dialogFrame.setOpacity(i);
                        Thread.sleep(15);
                    }
                    dialogFrame.dispose();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            };
        }.start();

    }

    public void setUploader(Uploader callerUploader) {
        this.callerUploader = callerUploader;
    }

    public void set(int n) {
        progressBar.setValue(n);
        progressBar.setString(n + "");
    }

    public void setMessage(String headingLabel) {
        this.headingLabel.setText(headingLabel);
        autoPosition();
        dialogFrame.setShape(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(1, 1, 200, 50, 20, 20));
        dialogFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void setWait() {
        headingLabel.setText("Waiting link...");
    }

    public void close() {
        dialogFrame.dispose();
    }

    public void stoppedUploaderClose() {
        try {
            callerUploader.stopUpload();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: For more direct help, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) or a [minimal example program/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem. We don't want your entire program, just one that demonstrates the problem -- less code for us volunteers to go through.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're making Swing calls that change the state of the Swing components of GUI from within a background thread, and this can and will lead to unpredictable errors. Better to use a Swing Timer rather than `Thread.sleep(...)` since all code within the Timer's ActionListener is called on the Swing event thread.

Also, I have to wonder

1. Just what the Uploader class does,... Likely it creates long running code, which begs the question, is it being called appropriately within a background thread? This looks like a good spot for a SwingWorker.
2. How is this dialog code being called?

For more direct help, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) or a [minimal example program/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Edit: OK, I normally don't do this, but I looked at your code in your [GitHub project link](https://github.com/KSUploader/KSUploader-client/blob/master/src/ProgressDialog.java), and as I suspected, Uploader does long-running code **on** the Swing event thread, and makes calls to this class you've posted above. I suggest that you use a SwingWorker for long-running code, that you use its `setProgress(...)` method to change its progress state from 0 to 100, and that you use a PropertyChangeListener to listen for changes to this state, and then set the JProgressBar's value based on this. It will take a lot of work on your part, but will be well worth it. For the details, look at: [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

I have some example SwingWorker programs that you can find here:

- [Cant get JProgressBar to update from SwingWorker class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25694838/522444)
- [MVC Progress Bar Threading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5533581/522444)
- [How do I make my SwingWorker example work properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10240173/522444)
- [JProgressBar without JButton and PropertyChangeListener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26005536/522444)
- [Understanding Java ExecutorService](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25963520/522444)

Comment: Are you talking about the destroy() method? It is the only one with a thread and a thread.sleep. If yes it doesn't generate the dialog, but simply destroy it and isn't called at the moment by nothing.

Comment: @SergiX44: initially yes, but now I suspect that the problem lies with your Uploader class and its calls. I still suspect a Swing threading issue, but your question is incomplete, and so now is my answer. I'm considering deleting my answer until you can give us more pertinent information.

Comment: I just tried to create a main and run it and... works. You can see the entire project here: .https://github.com/KSUploader/KSUploader-client/blob/master/src/ProgressDialog.java The ProgressDialog is called (in a first time) by Zipper.java (that must compress a file showing the progress status in the dialog)

Comment: For more direct help, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) or a [minimal example program/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem. We don't want your entire program, just one that demonstrates the problem -- less code for us volunteers to go through.

Comment: @SergiX44: see edit: yeah, you've got Swing threading issues in a big way. Your code has too much cyclomatic complexity to allow me to create a simple easy to post fix, but with some effort, you should be able to either fix it, or simplify your classes to allow us to better help you.

Comment: This is a little example of what happen on the client with only the interested classes and works: http://www.mediafire.com/download/tg6wfavc6qil51y/DialogBugTest.zip
The strange thing is that I don't understand where is the thread issue since that the dialog is called by the zipper that is called by the systemtraymenu that is called by main. No Thread.run() are present.

Comment: @SergiX44: There never should be `new Thread(...).run()` present. But your code **should** have `new Thread(...).start()` present or better `new MySwingWorker.execute()` somewhere to run your long-running processes off of the Swing event thread, but your code doesn't.

Comment: @SergiX44: You're welcome! So, do you have it fixed?